How do I reduce the size of my physical gpt partitioned disk?
I have a Rocky 8 system on a 1024GB disk consisting of a /boot and a / partition on LVM, using a gpt partition table.
I have to move this to a replacement 1000GB disk, which is slightly smaller.
Moving the LVM disk is trivial using pvmove, and not a problem.
What are the steps required to:

Partition the target drive.
Move the /boot partition across from the one disk to the other.
Make sure the system stays bootable.

Is there a tool that can run from a rescue disk, and that can achieve this goal?
I tried copying the first 2GB of the disk with dd (covering the /boot partition), expecting to be able to pvcreate the rest, but ended up with an unreadable partition. Copying the data seems really easy, making the system boot again is a mystery.

These are the steps that eventually worked for me.

Install a throwaway copy of the same operating system on the target slightly smaller drive, and make sure you can boot into it. This gives you a working /boot, /boot/efi and bootable partition.

Bring up the system on a rescue disk, do not mount either the source or target disks.

Destroy the LVM physical volume containing the throwaway on the target disk, leaving behind the /boot and /boot/efi partitions.

Create a new LVM physical volume on the target disk, and pvmove all the data from the source disk to the target disk.

Update /etc/fstab on the target disk to mount /boot and /boot/efi correctly, either by device path or by UUID as needed.

Reboot the rescue disk, this time mounting the target system. Once you chroot to the target system, you should have at least /, /boot and /boot/efi correctly mounted. If not, fix /etc/fstab and try again.

Force the reinstall of all grub2 and shim packages as follows, or force reinstall them from your installation disk:


dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-*


Rebuild the grub config by running the following:

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg


Remove all kernels from your target system. The replacement of the /boot drive above means the kernels the RPM database think exist and that actually exist in /boot are different, this restores sanity.

rpm --erase --allmatches kernel-*


Install one kernel on your system. This could come from dnf with 'dnf install kernel', or from local installation media.

At this point your target system should have a fresh /boot and /boot/efi, and at least one working kernel.
Reboot without the rescue disk and your system should come back up.
